# Determining the multiplicative group of a ring of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let us say that we have the polynomial ring R[x]. Would it be possible to determine the order of the multiplicative group of R[x] modulo a polynomial f?

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent of Euler's theorem for polynomials:

> **Theorem:** (Euler's Theorem for Polynomials).
>
> Let $m \in K[x]$, where $K$ is a finite field, and let
> $$\varphi(m) = \#\{f \in K[x] : 0 <= deg(f)< deg(m) \text{ and } gcd(f, m) = 1\}$$
> Where here $\#(A)$ denotes the cardinal of the set $A$ up to a multiplication by a constant ($f$ and $af$ with $a\in K$ are counted only one time). Then for any $f \in K[x]$ with $gcd(f, m) = 1$,
> $$f^{\varphi(m)}= 1 (\mod m)$$

see [this document](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a218148.pdf) for more information.

Comment: I corrected it, maybe if you look in the internet for "Euler's Theorem for Polynomials" you can find better than this document